# To Add colors for column cell text based on conditions in react-virtualised table

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I am using table & column components from react-virtualised module.

I have a requirement to add color to cell text based on few conditions. I did not find a way to do so.

[This is the Link for code reference](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/issues/1285)

Please help me for solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution using cell renderer

```
getColorPalate(risk) {
    let riskColor;
    switch (true) {
        case risk < 25:
            riskColor = '#00CD63';
            break;
        case risk > 25 && risk < 50:
            riskColor = '#F8E71C';
            break;
        case risk > 50 && risk < 75:
            riskColor = '#F09502';
            break;
        default:
            riskColor = '#F24343';
            break;
    }
    return ( < div style = {
                {
                    color: riskColor,
                }
            } > {
                risk
            } < /div> ); }
```